# de Broglie wavelength ignores rest mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, frequency, wavelength, dispersion

The de Broglie wavelength for matter is mimicking how light is treated

i.e.
$$E=hf=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

and

$$E^2=m_0^2c^4+p^2c^2\rightarrow E=pc$$

give $$\lambda=\frac{h}{p}.$$

The matter wave wavelength takes this same form but this relation relies on the fact that $m_0=0$, so $\lambda=h/p$ should not translate directly to massive particles due to the extra $m_0^2c^4$ term.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is difficult to follow, but maybe the following should help with the confusion: yes, the relation between energy and momentum is different for a massive particle, but the relation between the frequency and the wave vector (or between the period and the wavelength) is also different for it.

Comment: Sorry English is not my first language, my question was not asked in the best way. Do you mean $\lambda=h/p$ is a postulation without proof, rather we need different expression of $E=hf$ for massive particles?

Comment: @ltf : There is a different relation between $f$ and $\lambda$ for massive particles.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of de Broglie is that $\lambda=h/p$ **should** translate directly to massive particles **in spite of** the $m_0^2c^4$ term. Your statement of the contrary dismisses the essence of de Broglie's contribution.